# xcode adding button to uitabbarcontroller is not clickable on landscape

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I am adding a simple button into a view on a tabbarcontroller to the bottom right of the view. This button is clickable only when it is on portrait, not when the app is flipped to landscape. The app is using autolayout, so I've added two constraints so it hugs the bottom right of the view on landscape and portrait. Horizontal space at 20 and Vertical space at 24. I've tried this on a UIViewController without the UITabBarController, and it works perfectly. But once the view is added to a tab, it stops working. How do I get this button clickable on both portrait and landscape?

This seems like a very simple setup, but I have no idea why this does not work.

![snapshot2]http://ownits-stackoverflow.s3.amazonaws.com/snapshot2.png
![snapshot3]http://ownits-stackoverflow.s3.amazonaws.com/snapshot3.png

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing it works. Here is the sample code try to run it on your own simulator and on device.

[Sample Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7ul8tirjfbn8aq/Test.zip)